# calculating degenerancy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantum-mechanics

Given a function of two positive integers $n_x^2+n_y^2$.

$n_x^2+n_y^2=50$ has three combinations of $n_x$ and $n_y$ that result in $n_x^2+n_y^2=50$:

$$n_x=7,n_y=1$$ 
$$n_x=5,n_y=5$$
$$n_x=1,n_y=7$$

I need to find the net highest integer such that there are three or more combinations of $n_x$ and $n_y$ that result in this number, but I have no clue how to go about it, other than by trial and error. Can anyone point me in the right direction? A hint would be preferable.

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with discrete math or quantum mechanics, but... there are infinitely many integers that can be expressed as the sum of two squares in at least three ways. Take any two primes of the form $4k+1$ and multiply them together, for instance.

Comment: Hi, any feedback on my answer would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

Allowing zeros and distinguishing signs and order, you could use the [Sum of Two Squares Function $r_2(n)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html).
It is related to [Jacobi's $\vartheta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html): $\vartheta_3^2(q)$ is known as the generating function of $r_2(n)$.

So other than trail and error, you could [Taylor expand $\vartheta_3^2(q)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427epf020d08g1) the orders $50+$ and check if the coefficient is higher than $3\cdot 4=12$, since pairs of squares are split into four, due to signs.

> The next higher integer is $65=1^2+8^2=8^2+1^2=7^2+6^2=6^2+7^2$